# how to see if php session has been set by using jquery

Tags: jquery

Do i have to do something like `var session = "<?php = $_SESSION['sessionname'] ?>";`
Or is there a jquery statement for it?

I want to be able to check if the session exists using jquery

I need to do this because, when the user inputs his username, an ajax loads a php file to validate it. This php starts a session if the email does not match. I tried JSON but it did not seem to work for me.
I will be happy to hear any other way to solve this as well :)

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: PHP sessions only exist on the server, not the client. You could use an AJAX call to find out.

Comment: You can use ajax to check on that. Just be aware that you will need `session_start()` in your php.
Personally I would be very careful in sending $_SESSION data through ajax. The results will be visible in the console to everybody with some smarts.

Answer (score 0):

php session is in the server side, not in the client side. The following is another method...

You can use the following plugin 
https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

```
// To Store
$(function() {
    $.session.set("myVar", "value");
});


// To Read
$(function() {
    alert($.session.get("myVar"));
});
```

Comment: The sessions created with this plugin are not the same as PHP sessions.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
    action: "session"
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    success: function (json) {
        console.log(json.sessionvalue);
        if(json.session == "true"){
           // code here
        }
    }
});
```

On php side

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'session'){
  session_start();
  return json_encode(array("sessionvalue" => $_SESSION['mysessionvar']));
}
```

You can also assign multidemensional arrays

```
$array = array("sessions"=>array('value1', 'value2', 'value3'), 'numbers'=>array(0,5,6,8));

return json_encode($array);
```

Values can be retrieved by using json.sessions[0] etc ..

When you commit ajax calls, you should always work with the [console](http://gardengnomesoftware.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console)

Comment: So, that is going to return the json array value? .. how do set function like `if (json.array == somethin)`

Comment: Added some info ...  Just play with your array. Make it associative and multidimensional and see what comes back in your console.