# using jquery variable in php

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I've got a dynamic table filled by a recordset from MYSQL.
Each row has it's own delete button (image) to delete the specific row.
This button has a class="button".

I'm using a JQuery popup modal to get a popup when a delete button is clicked.
In this JQuery script i'm creating a variable which contains the numeric value of the first td cel of the row that has been clicked on.
This all works perfectly.

What i'm trying to accomplish is to use this variable on the same php page.
Here is where my knowledge runs out.
I've read some examples where Ajax is the solution for this, but i lack the knowledge to use these examples for this solution.

JQuery code:

```
<script src="../javascript/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="../javascript/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.button').click(function(e) { // Button which will activate our modal
         var value=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
         alert(value); // this works
         $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
            animation: 'fade', // fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 500, // how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: false, // if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close' // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
         });
      return false;
      });
   });
</script>
```

I've been trying too much that i don't see the logic anymore.
I hope that someone can help me with this.

Comment: What do you want to do with that variable? Is it needed in the same page or will you be passing it to a different php script?

Comment: I need this variable so i can use it when clicking on a yes button in de popup modal.
<a href="delete_verlof.php?id=<?php echo $thisvariableneedstobefilledwithjqueryvariable ?>" class="button green close"><img  src="../images/tick.png">Yes</a>

Comment: How do you want to use it when clicking the "yes" button? Do you want to send it to the server?

Comment: There is an abundance of information on using Ajax to get to the back-end. I explained it to somebody yesterday with a example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330547/how-to-see-if-php-session-has-been-set-by-using-jquery/16330713?noredirect=1#comment23388732_16330713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your JavaScript runs in the client -- the user's web browser -- while your PHP runs on your server. It's a two-stage process: first, all the PHP is executed on the server and the HTML is rendered, which is then sent to the client (the browser). Then, the client executes all the JavaScript on the page.

You need some way to communicate the JS variable (`value`) to your server if you want to be able to use it in your PHP code. AJAX is one such way, but it would be helpful to have more information on how exactly you want to use this information in your PHP.

Edit: based on your comments above, something like this should work. You'll have to give your Yes button an `id` attribute (here I'm assuming the `id` is `yesButton`).

```
$(.button).click(function() {
    var value=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
    $("#yesButton").attr("href", "delete_verlof.php?id=" + value);
    $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
        animation: 'fade', // fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 500, // how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: false, // if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close' // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
    });
    return false;
});
```

The important thing to note is that the JS variable *does not exist yet* at the time at which your PHP executes, so it is not available to the PHP. What I've done here instead is to dynamically change the `href` of the Yes button whenever the user clicks a `td`, which should have the desired effect.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I need this variable back in php so i can delete the row that has been clicked. offcourse there is a better way to do this i guess, but if this can be done, i can implement it for other cases as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your using this in a form, then you could create a hidden input field with a unique id and add it with.

```
$('#idOfField').val(value);
```

And then use php to get the element from wherever you put it in your code.

Other then you might find attr usefull. For an example

```
$('#idOfField').attr('data-id', value);
```

Where the ID can be an div, span, i, a, bold, strong etc etc etc.

Comment: unfortunately it's not in a form

Comment: Updated the answer. Still don't know if im on the right track as the results your looking for is a bit vague.